# TestFlight- Not able to select version

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

I have submitted an app to iOS store.  I want to select version to user for TestFlight.

But I am unable to select version . it is still showing processing after 24 hours too.

Here is screenshot. it is disabled

[image]

I am using 
App store under 
Distribution Provisional profile. When i submitted an app to iOS store. it was successfully submitted without any error.

Is there is any issue ?
Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have the answer.

The trick is to create a distribution profile at Apple for "Distribution to the App Store", not "ad hoc distribution".  Previously I had to use "ad hoc" so that I could specify devices and use (the non-Apple) TestFlight. It now seems that using an "ad hoc" profile and it's associated devices will omit the beta-reports-active entitlement (this changed sometime in the past two weeks I think). This is probably the root cause of the (somewhat) erroneous error message in iTunesConnect, which should say something like "Don't use an adhoc profile".

Answer (score 2):

It's intresting to share knowledge at this point. Recently had such a problem. But at least we succeed:
[image]

First, of all we had some errors during uploading - like transparent backgrounds at icon images. When we fixed them after loading the build in output we got message, that our app is rather big to check up all the errors and will be proceed and become available in some moment.

As you see, we have only 1 build succeed. What helped us:

- Naming the build not the same, as app version
- Playing with flag `Embedded content contains Swift code`

Comment: i didn't  get any error while uploading from Xcode. i got message successfully submitted

Comment: To use TestFlight Beta Testing, this build must contain the correct beta entitlement. For more information,